# AJAX stops working after abort() onPopstate

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, abort, popstate

I am using the following code to **abort()** in the event there is an uncompleted AJAX call when the user clicks the forward / back button. It all works great to abort the call but after that future calls on the function will not work. When I try and call swapContent() after the abort, it does nothing. How do I call on the AJAX function again after aborting?

**Global**

```
var ajax;
```

**AJAX**

```
function swapContent() {

    ajax = $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        data: params,
        url: 'content.php',

        success: function(data) {
            $('#browser').html(data);
        },

        error:function(e){
          // Error
        }
    });
}
```

**onPopstate**

```
$(window).on('popstate', function() {

    // Abort active requests
    if(ajax && ajax.readystate != 4){
        ajax.abort();
    }

});
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. [It seems to complete the second call](https://jsfiddle.net/n7d5j8wj/1/) after the first one aborts.

Answer (score 0):

Set ajax back to null:

```
$(window).on('popstate', function() {
    if(ajax && ajax.readystate != 4){
        ajax.abort();
        ajax = null;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this works....

**Global**

```
var ajax;
```

**AJAX**

```
function swapContent() {

    ajax = $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        data: params,
        url: 'content.php',

        // -- VERIFY AJAX IS NULL -- //

        beforeSend : function()    {           
                    if(ajax != null) {
                        ajax.abort(); // ABORT IF NOT NULL
                    }
        },

        success: function(data) {
            $('#browser').html(data);
            ajax = null; // NULL AJAX ON SUCCESS
        },

        error:function(e){
          // Error
        }
    });
}
```

**onPopstate**

```
$(window).on('popstate', function() {
    if(ajax && ajax.readystate != 4){
        ajax.abort();
        ajax = null; // NULL AFTER ABORT
    }
});
```